# In my React app I can't figure out how to pass the value of an input box to a button's onclick

Tags: reactjs, spinner

The scenario is an unknown number of input boxes are created with their own send button. A user enters some value and with onclick this value and a URI associated with that input is sent to a function which concatenates the two values and opens in the browser. I have done this in plain JS and in Angular 9 but I cannot figure out how to do this in React. I am only five days in my React adventure and I suspect my approach is incorrect.

In Angular I would create a reference to the input box and in my onclick I would add `reference.value`. How can I do that in React?

This is most likely a duplicate but I've been unable to find a QA that fits my use case.

[Stackblitz starter app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zesssu), right now it just passes a string.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  
  handleClick(data){
    alert(data)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <input placeholder='enter data' />
        </form>
        <br />
        <botton className='btn' onClick={() => this.handleClick('test')}>Click</botton>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This link from [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) would help you a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by using `React.useRef`:

```js
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const ref = React.useRef();

  const handleClick = (data) => {
    alert(data)
  }

  return (
    <div>
        <form>
          <input ref={ref} placeholder='enter data' />
        </form>
        <br />
        <botton className='btn' onClick={() => handleClick(ref.current.value)}>Click</botton>
      </div>
  );
}
```

[See example on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-goldstine-xq0bz?file=/src/App.js).

Although, I would go with a different approach (get the value from the method and not from the call itself:

```js
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const ref = React.useRef();

  const handleClick = () => {
    if (ref) {
      alert(ref.current.value);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <input ref={ref} placeholder="enter data" />
      </form>
      <br />
      <botton className="btn" onClick={handleClick}>
        Click
      </botton>
    </div>
  );
}
```